# Change name of standard object in managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package

I need to create a script to rename the salesforce standard object, or when i create the package include the new names. I create a Managed Package, this package will be need the new name of the santdard object because I changed them.

For example the object `Account`, now call `Pacient`.

Comment: I wonder... do you mean just to provide an alternative label for the customer's language?

Answer (score 4):

Neither is directly possible. Further, you should not try to rename standard objects, as your package needs to co-exist with other packages. Your customers need to be able to choose what they want to call "Accounts". If you're not really using Accounts, but something else, you should have created a Custom Object to reflect that usage. This way, you could have called it whatever you wanted to without interfering with your customers' naming conventions. Even NPSP (The Non-Profit Success Pack) introduces new record types (e.g. Households), but does not alter the name of the standard objects directly.